# Eval after every train epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Trying to get a workflow using tensorflow object detection API.

I have created a tfrecords for my training set (4070 images) and my validation set (1080 images).

Training goes for 400 iterations then switches to evaluation where it takes a quite a long time (about 10 minutes) then proceeds to repeat the evaluation for ever. I've been confused why I'm getting poor performance but it seems that I train for only 10mins despite running for 24hours.

Eval config is

```
   eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 30
  num_examples: 30
  eval_interval_secs: 600
  max_evals: 1
  include_metrics_per_category: true
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "D:/src/Wind/WindObjectDetector/data/labels.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/src/Wind/WindObjectDetector/data/val.record"
  }
  sample_1_of_n_examples: 1
}
```

Training config:

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0010000000474974513
          decay_steps: 1017
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079071
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
      decay: 0.8999999761581421
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/src/Wind/WindObjectDetector/experiments/test2/tl/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 25400
}
```

What I really want is the workflow I had doing regular image classification and segmentation. That is, train for one epoch (num_images//batch_size iterations). Then evaluate on validation set for one epoch then repeat. So every loop I see every image once and evaluate on every (validation) image once. At this point I'd be happy to just have it train.

Answer (score 1):

Training and evaluation are two seperated steps in the object detection API. You have to run `train.py` for training and `eval.py` for evaluation. If you want to evaluate during training process both scripts have to run parallel. I can not really say why you are training only 10 minutes, without seeing the training part of your config file. How many steps do you train?

If you want to evaluate after every epoch, you have to generate a checkpoint after every single one (for changing the checkpoint generation frequency have a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5139#issuecomment-418963839)). When a new checkpoint is generated the eval script will automatically evaluate this new one.

Comment: Is this true anymore. Those scripts are in a legacy folder. There's now a single model_main file. I'll edit the main to add training config

Comment: Your are right, but the above solution will still work. Your training part looks fine. How long does it need to train those first 400 steps?

You should try to increase the number of `eval_interval_secs`. As this defines how often you run the evaluation (in seconds). Default is 600 seconds. If you say that evaluation takes 10 minutes, then it will start the next evaluation right after the previous ended, without training further.

Comment: I've changed eval_interval_secs with no change. Adding save_checkpoints_steps = num_img/batch_size works though